# print solution (new to C)

Tags: c

I cant figure out why my program wont print the final solution (totalDough). The inputs are 8,10,12 then 40,100 and 200:

```
const int DOUGH_PER_SQFT = 0.75;
const int INCHES_PER_FEET = 12;
#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846

int main(){

    // Declare and initialize variables

    int smallRIn;
    printf("What is the radius of your small pizza, in inches?\n");
    scanf("%d", &smallRIn);
    int mediumRIn;
    printf("What is the radius of your medium pizza, in inches?\n");
    scanf("%d", &mediumRIn);
    int largeRIn;
    printf("What is the radius of your large pizza, in inches?\n");
    scanf("%d", &largeRIn);


    // Get number of pizzas sold
    int smallSold;
    printf("How many small pizzas do you expect to sell this week?\n");
    scanf("%d", &smallSold);
    int mediumSold;
    printf("How many medium pizzas do you expect to sell this week?\n");
    scanf("%d", &mediumSold);
    int largeSold;
    printf("How many large pizzas do you expect to sell this week?\n");
    scanf("%d", &largeSold);

    // Convert radii to feet

    double smallRFeet, mediumRFeet, largeRFeet;
    smallRFeet = smallRIn/INCHES_PER_FEET;
    mediumRFeet = mediumRIn/INCHES_PER_FEET;
    largeRFeet = largeRIn/INCHES_PER_FEET;

    // Calculate top surface areas of each type of pizza.

    double areaSmall, areaMedium, areaLarge;
    areaSmall = smallSold*M_PI*pow(smallRFeet,2);
    areaMedium = mediumSold*M_PI*pow(mediumRFeet,2);
    areaLarge = largeSold*M_PI*pow(largeRFeet,2);

    // Print solution
    double dough;
    dough = areaSmall+areaMedium+areaLarge;
    double total_dough;
    total_dough = dough * DOUGH_PER_SQFT;

    printf("The total amount of dough you need to order this week is", total_dough);

    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would expect a smaller piece of code that doesn't work for you, a better headline and more about what you tried and how it failed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
const int DOUGH_PER_SQFT = 0.75;
```

This is of value int and int's are not floating-point numbers, so this translates to:

```
0
```

This basically means that in your final equation

```
total_dough = dough * DOUGH_PER_SQFT;
```

It will evaluate to 0 because dough per sqft is equal to 0.

This can be corrected by changing:

```
const int DOUGH_PER_SGFT = 0.75
```

into:

```
const double DOUGH_PER_SGFT = 0.75
```

Comment: Note that Clang warns about this: *warning: implicit conversion from 'double' to 'int' changes value from 0.75 to 0*. Using list-initialization would make that an error.

Comment: Thank you. Combined with the answer above, that does it. Now I just need the output to match the test case answer of 676.751417....lbs. Any idea there? I get 471.238???

Comment: Try changing the #define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846 into const double M_PI = 3.14159265358979323846

Comment: @corvette1: Try changing the type of `INCHES_PER_FEET` to `double`. The division `smallRIn/INCHES_PER_FEET` results in an integer as both values are integers. Ex: If `smallRIn == 8` this results in `8/12` which is `0`.

Comment: Also I would add not to forget using PEMDAS. This can be easily confused within a program, and will not result in an error message but will result in a faulty code. I don't see this as a problem here, though.

Comment: Thank all of you for your help on this. It now works.

Answer (score 3):

print stands for *print with format*, and you obviously forgot the format for the parameter **total_dought**.

I'd suggest to use compiler flags that generate warnings, if you use gcc, add -Wall.

Regarding the solution, replace:

```
printf("The total amount of dough you need to order this week is", total_dough);
```

By

```
printf("The total amount of dough you need to order this week is %f", total_dough);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

```
const int DOUGH_PER_SQFT = 0.75;
```

An integer cant store decimal so convert it to macro:

```
#define DOUGH_PER_SQFT  0.75
```

And

```
printf("The total amount of dough you need to order this week is", total_dough);
```

You are not printing the value. Convert it to:

```
printf("The total amount of dough you need to order this week is%f", total_dough);
```

The running code is at : http://ideone.com/aucOlW